# Using fgets for file read

Tags: c, for-loop, fgets

I'm new to using strings in C and am needing to read from a file lines of data that contain strings and numbers, parsing them as I go along.  I've done similar programs reading in just numbers, such as a list of ordered pairs, using a for loop so this is the strategy I am leaning towards.

Example of data line in the file: PART,2.000,-1,0.050,V

When I compile I get an error in the for loop declaration of "expected expression before 'char'".  What is missing or needs reviewing in this code?

```
#define flush fflush(stdin)
#define N 50

int main()
{
    flush;
    const char part[] = "PART";           // String for PART variable
    char descriptor[N];     // Starting string of data set
    double p_dim[N];         // Array for part dimensions
    int t_sens[N];          // Array for sensitivity values: -1 or +1
    double t[N];             // Array for part tolerance, bilateral
    char t_status[N];       // Array for tolerance status, F(ixed) or V(ariable)
    double key_max;  // Maximum value of key characteristic
    double key_min;  // Minimum value of key characteristic


    FILE* fpin;

    if((fpin = fopen("input.txt","r"))==(FILE*)NULL)
    {
        printf("File input does not exist\n"); exit(-1);
    }
// For loop to parse data lines from file    
    for(N; char* fgets(descriptor, int N, FILE* fpin); N-1);
        {
                 compare(descriptor, part);
            if (descriptor == part)
            {
                fscanf(fpin, "%lf,%d,%lf,%s", p_dim[N], t_sens[N], t[N], t_status[N]);
            }
            else if (descriptor != part)
            {
                fscanf(fpin, "%lf, %lf", &key_min, &key_max);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

1.) `#define flush fflush(stdin)`

Flushing `stdin` invokes undefined behaviour.

2.) `if((fpin = fopen("input.txt","r"))==(FILE*)NULL)`

The cast to `(FILE*)` is superfluous.

3.) `for(N; ... ; N-1);`

You defined `N` as a constant (`#define N 50`) so this loop won't ever exit.

4.) `for(... ; char* fgets(descriptor, int N, FILE* fpin); ...);`

This is just plain wrong ...

Comment: It's been a while since I've been in C so I found some of my novice errors.

Macro N is now NMAX

I'm not sure what you mean by superfluous, but this was a proven snip from a different program.

I realized my error in the for middle portion of the for declaration.  From the below comment I'm playing around with strtok now.

Answer (score 0):

I'd lean more toward breaking the string apart
See question 3501338 for reading a file line by line
See question 15472299 using strtok to break apart the string
If you need to cast the strings as numbers use sscanf

Comment: I looked at these posts from your suggestion but I'm not very good at interpreting others programming, and some of it is more advanced than what I'll be using for now.

Comment: Would it be better using a MD array for storing these?  I've not mastered them so I'd need a refresher.